# TYPO3 Filelist: In which way I can set the title / description instead of the filename at TYPO3 7.6.2?

Tags: upload, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, filelist, typo3-7.6.x

I have a problem using the filelist / upload element of TYPO3 at the current new version 7.6.2. I want to use the title or description part instead of the filename while rendering the list.

I found lots of information on that and in TYPO3 version 6.x it worked with:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj = COA
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.1.data = file:current:title
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.30 >
```

When I insert this lines into the TS of the page where I want to use the filelist it does not work with the new css_styled_content for 7.x.

When I include "CSS Styled Content TYPO3 v6.2 (css_styled_content)" to the setup of the template, the filelist works (but other parts of page not).

Therefore the question: Do you know if there are some changes in rendering the filelist at 7.x?

Thanks for your help
Markus

Comment: it looks at least weird, in 7.6.x setup for uploads is identical as in 6.2.x and it renders title field without problems if given, without need to manually adjusting it! Ust __TypoScript Object Browser__ to check what value there is in: `tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.data` it should be: `file:current:title // file:current:name`

Comment: Thanks for that, it is weird, yes. I took a look at the Object Browser and I exactly find what you said: `file:current:title // file:current:name` for that entry but when I view the page I get the filename at the end. When I change there something, e.g. for the CSS wrap around that as well, nothing changes (saved, cache clear, reload).

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you have some TypoScript on lower level which overrides it again ? (sorry just blind shooting) I just checked behavior on fresh 7.6.2 and everything is all right

Comment: It is the lowest level, that's what confuses me as well. When I include the old "CSS Styled Content TYPO3 v6.2 (css_styled_content)" it works. Bu I dont want to do so because then I get other errors like "ERROR: Content Element type "textmedia" has no rendering definition!". And I think it does not make sense to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't change the name => title anymore is that you included **Fluid Styled Content** ext which is required i.e. for rendering the **Text & Media** CEtype. It massively overrides the CSS styled content and replaces *(almost)* whole TS declarations with Fluid templates/layouts/partials from `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private` folder. I.e.: in `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/Uploads.html:29` there is `{file.name}` used which should be more advanced condition...

To change it:

1. Copy all folders from `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private` to your custom destination i.e.: `fileadmin/fluid_styled_content/Private` (this is for avoiding loosing of your changes after system upgrade.
   It can be any other path, for an instance you can create your custom ext and put it into `typo3conf/ext/yourext/Resources/Private/...`
2. Go to your **TypoScript template** > **Constant Editor** > **Category: Content** and set new paths in these fields:

   - **Path of Fluid Templates...** - `fileadmin/fluid_styled_content/Private/Templates`
   - **Path of Fluid Partials...** - `fileadmin/fluid_styled_content/Private/Partials`
   - **Path of Fluid Layouts...** - `fileadmin/fluid_styled_content/Private/Layouts`

After that go to `fileadmin/fluid_styled_content/Private/Templates/Uploads.html:29` and replace the code:

```
{file.name}
```

with:

```
<f:if condition="{file.title}"><f:then>{file.title}</f:then><f:else>{file.name}</f:else></f:if>
```

As you can see this way you can also change other CEtypes and their typical settings (i.e. add the responsive classes if working with RWD).

On the other hand take a look there are some drawbacks of this solution, i.e. default layouts repeats the `<div id="c123">...` which is invalid :/

**P.S.:**

Also just realized that Fluid Styled Content doesn't handle other things, i.e. different layouts for Uploads (that the first thing I saw, didn't check other CEtypes) so you need to consider yourself if it is OK for your project at the moment. I prefer to stay with *old way* (no need for Text & Media CE) and disable FSC now (I'm pretty sure, that soon it will be nice alternative for CSC, but not now imho :/) To *revert* typical state you can use these lines mentioned in the [**GitHub here**](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/261#issuecomment-160615893) within your PageTS.

Comment: just to clearify: don't copy all files from `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private` into your folders. you may copy all folders. But in general: only copy those files (with the original relative path) into your *copy* where you want to override the original with your modification.